# 403 error while saving in global configuration

Tags: joomla-3.x

When i wanna save changes that I've made in global configuration, 403 error page comes up. This error also comes up in some other places. Recently I've installed "JCH plugin" "rs firewall" . I have "admin tools" too.

error:

```
403
Forbidden

Access to this resource on the server is denied!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apparently](https://www.akeebabackup.com/support/admin-tools/12915-repair-a-optimise-tables-403-access-forbidden.html#p75304) RS Firewall filters back-end requests. If this feature can't be disabled, the first thing I'd try is to disable or remove RS Firewall to see if this solves the issue.

Assuming you have the Pro version of Admin Tools, then you may have two web application firewalls enabled on your website. This is a bit like installing two virus protection programs on your computer and is a recipe for disaster (both programs trying to scrutinise the same incoming requests at the same time). I'd be inclined to keep one of Admin Tools Pro or RS Firewall (but not both).

Some other things to try:

- update to the latest version of Joomla (if you haven't already)
- update third party extensions to the latest versions (if you haven't already)
- clear the Joomla cache
- clear your web browser cache
- temporarily switch to an alternative admin template to see if this helps
- temporarily switch to an alternative PHP version to see if this helps (e.g. if you are on PHP 7, switch back to 5.6)
- temporarily disable any third party administrator modules (choose Administrator from the drop down filter at `Extensions -> Modules`)
- temporarily disable any third party plugins to see if this helps
- rename your `.htaccess` file to `.htaccess.old` and copy the default
  `htaccess.txt` to `.htaccess` to test if the issue may be caused by
  something in your `.htaccess` file
- try temporarily disabling `mod_security` if it is loaded (see https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/9638/120 and https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/4969/120 for examples of how to do this)
- back up your website and try running a manual install of the latest
  joomla install file for your version of Joomla e.g.
  Joomla_3.6.2-Stable-Full_Package.zip as per the manual install
  procedure at
  https://docs.joomla.org/Updating_Joomla_%28Manual_Method%29 or similar

Comment: which one is better? rs firewall pro   or    admin tools pro?

Comment: i uninstalled "rs firewall" and "admin tools" but the problem still remains! i deleted .htaccess but still..

Comment: They no doubt both have their strengths and weaknesses and it probably depends on what you need and want so you are probably the only one who can answer this question.

Comment: I added some other ideas to try